# Python giving import errors

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I have some code with the following structure:

```
+main-folder
   +Foo-folder/
       +foo
       +bar
       -file1.py
       -file2.py

  +bar-folder
      +bars
```

I'm trying to do a simple import like so:

```
#Some module in +foo
from foo-folder.file1 import some-module
```

so in Pycharm it works fine but when I run it from the command line. I get moduleNotFoundError.
I'm using python 3.7 so I have no **init**.py files in them. Any idea about this?

Thanks,

Comment: So this sounds like a difference between what directory pycharm is running the interpreter from and what directory you are running it from the command line. Go check the pycharm settings to see what directory it's running the project from.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim yeah I tried going into the working pycharm directory and the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When some module import works from PyCharm but not from the command line, it's usually because PyCharm automatically adds your project files to the Pythonpath.

In any case, also check your run configuration in PyCharm. What does it say is your working directory? Which directory are you starting it from when running from the command line?

Comment: Looks like that's what it was. I added my directory to the python path and works fine from the CLI now. Thanks. Actually glad it wasn't a Python3 issue. Didn't want it to be yet another thing in this transition. much appreciated. upvoted.